# While loop to write in several text files

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some lines of text in different text files.

The problem is that I can't close the first one and move to the next one using a while loop.

I want to use a while loop because the number of files that I want to create is undefined, so at the end of each case I want the program to ask me if I have finished working, like this:

```
status = input('finished? ')
```

If the answer is YES, I want the program to stop. If the answer is NO, I want the program to continue creating .txt files and printing the information I have specified.

```
import sys

while True:
    file_txt = str(input('.txt file name? ')+'.txt')
    sys.stdout = open(file_txt, "w")

    print('This will be printed in the file')

    sys.stdout.close()

    status = input('finished? ')
    if status == 'yes':
        break
    else:
        continue
```

The problem with this code is that I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess where does `input('finished? ')` write the text? In the `sys.stdout` you just closed! Try setting it back to console

```
sys.stdout = open(file_txt, "w")

print('This will be printed in the file')

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Comment: Thanks mate it's working perfectly now.

Comment: @Santiago I highly recommend to use [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227451/8564999)'s answer though. You better just write to file directly, without messing with `stdout` and `print`

Answer (score 4):

Unclear why you need `sys` module. Just write to a file object

Specifically, closing the system stream closes it for good

```
while True:
    file_txt = input('.txt file name? ')+'.txt'
    
    with open(file_txt, "w") as f:
        f.write('This will be printed in the file') 
    status = input('finished? ')
    if status == 'yes':
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless there's more code at the bottom of the loop, there's no need to `continue`.

You're trying to write to `sys.stdout` (standard output) by using `print`. After closing `sys.stdout`, you reset it. However, when I run your code (from unix), it seems as though `input` accesses stdout when you type anything into `stdout`- even if you haven't typed anything.